# How to use ASP.NET Configuration on external SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, configuration

In visual studio there is a nice possibility to manage users and memberships for an ASP.NET site. I moved the membership data from SQLEXPRESS to a normal SQL server. The website works fine, however how do i now manage my users/profiles/etc... like I was used to in visual studio? Is it possible to tell vs2010 to 'look' into the new sql server database in stead of the apsnetdb.mdf file?

Thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:

In your web.config file, under the connectionStrings section, name your connection string, `LocalSqlServer`, i.e.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Server=123.123.123.123;Database=dbName;User ID=dbuser;Password=dbPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Your role and membership providers, if have the `connectionStringName` set, change them to `LocalSqlServer` otherwise, the default providers "should" automatically refer to `LocalSqlServer` anyway.

In VS2010, I then simply go to Project > ASP.NET Configuration which will start the tool to manage users, roles etc.

HTH